# VFP autocomplete with cursors

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, visual-foxpro

I am using Visual FoxPro 9.0. i am having a problem, i would like to use autocomplete in some texboxes in my program. i have been searching and i have found that it doesnt work with cursors but with tables, but i dont have any tables because im using SQL servr 2008 and i execute sql queries using SQLEXE and placing the results in a cursor.

So i would like to know if any of yo have found any way to do this.

```
thisform.emp_cnombre.AutoComplete = 1
thisform.emp_cnombre.AutoCompSource =sgviemp
```

where sgviemp is a cursor result of a query

Thanks

Comment: AutoCompSource doesn't expect the name of a table or cursor. It's an identifier you give to a set of fields to say that they all share the same set of autocomplete data. Read the help for that property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking VFP Help, I see many things to take over:

First of all, to use a cursor as a table - cursor is the result of sqlexec() or select... into cursor - you can use the function **dbf()**:

```
sqlexec(gnCones,"select * from table","cr_sql_res")

thisform.txtName.AutoCompTable=dbf("cr_sql_res")
thisform.txtName.AutoCompSource="cr_sql_res.field_name"
```

And as you can see in the previous example, I think you left the `AutoCompSource`  property, although I have not ever used, because, I think that what you are trying to do, is what a **comboBox** does

Here are some VFP Screenshot help:

[image]

[image]